# call batch by web service in .net

Tags: wcf, batch-file

I have a batch script that takes as a parameter the source to an image and outputs the image modified. Can I place the batch on a server and call it by means of a webservice?

Comment: Yes, many ways. What have you tried so far and what problems you had?

Comment: I am looking for a basic example of how to use it. I don't know where to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get you started, here is some information and pointers to different alternatives. Try them and see which one more closely solves your requirements and work for you.

The simplest, just invoke Process.Start() passing the full filespec to the batch file

```
Process.Start("c:\bats\test.bat")
```

If you need more control, you might create a Process.StartInfo and pass it to the Process.Start method. I have not tested this code.

```
Process p= new Process();
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\temp";
p.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\bats\test.bat";
p.StartInfo.Arguments =  "arguments";
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

A little bit more convoluted way is running a CMD and sending commands to it. See this article http://codebetter.com/brendantompkins/2004/05/13/run-a-bat-file-from-asp-net/
However, this is a pretty rough and brute force batch execution, that may not work for all BAT files (for example those that have FOR commands with %% variables) and have some side effects.

Comment: thank you, however I would like to ask also how do you invoke with a parameter like test.bat -n 5

Comment: try changing "arguments" in the example to "-n 5"